# SQL query to fetch records based on related id in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table Structure:**

[image]

**I Tried this:**

```
select Id, Name from Color where ParentId=4
UNION
select Id, Name from Color where ParentId=(select Id from Color where ParentId=4)
```

Above approach is static in this case I have to know all the Ids. I'm looking something dynamic approach since I would have only Color's ParentId value.

As example: For ParentId=4 there are two records; Name Blue and Red their Id is 6 and 10 respectively. Now here, I need to get all the records where Id 6 and 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, ParentId  
    FROM Color 
    WHERE ParentId = @parentIdValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.Id, c2.Name, c2.ParentId  
    FROM cte c1
    INNER JOIN Color c2 ON c2.ParentId = c1.Id
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81956/sql-query-to-fetch-records-based-on-related-id-in-the-same-table)

Comment: It seems we are close. but I'm getting error: Invalid column name 'ParentId'. This error for this Line: INNER JOIN Color c2 ON c2.Id = c1.ParentId

Comment: @AshwiniVerma Sorry, I forgot to select the `ParentId` column. See my edit